# How to rewrite from /page to /xx/page, using htaccess & apache only?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, redirect, rewrite

Visualise a three step jump sporting event, with the first two steps perfect in place and the third step launching into air, never coming back and eventually a crash! That is what this question boils down to :)

**STEP 1:WORKS** serve `/somepage?ln=xx` when user navigates to `/xx/somepage`.

```
# if user inputs nice urls /xx/somepage  to serve page /someapge?ln=xx
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*) /$2?ln=$1 [L]
```

**STEP 2:WORKS** go to the homepage when only language is given /xx/

```
# if language xx given but no page given? then redirect to its home /xx/home
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/?$ /$1/home [R=301,L]
```

**STEP 3:CRASH**

```
# if user inputs /somepage then redirect to default english: /en/somepage
# if user inputs /somepage?ln=xx redirect to nice url /xx/somepage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/../ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The third rule is where we are stuck... PS: The redirection should work both for extensionless files *somepage?ln=xx* as well as files with extension *somepage.abc?ln=xx* where the extension can be any 2 or 3 char-word, or if easier, checked manually with the following extensions i use [.php .uu .u3c .vls]

Thanks a Thousand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does work (tested):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/../ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en$1 [R=301,L]
```

Apache [Mod_Rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), [Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html), and [Advanced Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide_advanced.html).

**Edit:**
Tested the above (it's the same as it was before); works on my Apache 2.2 server.

**Edit 2:**
Should be no problem, just need something like this:

```
# If just the language is specified (ie example.com/en)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/..$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/

# If no language subfolder, default to 'en'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/../ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en$1 [R=301]

# If no page specified, default to home.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/../.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(..) /$1/home.html [R=301]

# If no ln query, tack it on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !ln= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(..)/(.*) /$1/$2?ln=$1 [R=301]
```

Note: Be careful your 404 page works correctly. If it doesn't invalid links will end up in an infinite loop (ie, the 404 page wont work).
Note 2: If the user types in `example.com/en`, they will be redirected to `example.com/en/en?ln=en`, so be sure the tailing slash is in the URL, or else.
Note 3: If you want, you can drop the `[R=301]` from the last rule, then users will see `example.com/en/home.html` the request to the page will actually be `example.com/en/home.html?ln=en`. This will not work if your site uses GET requests though.

**Edit 3:**
Added another cond/rule pair to catch if someone types in just the language, without a trailing slash.

Comment: thanks Chris, but gives error: page isn't redirecting properly and nothing appears.

Comment: @Sam, just checked it, it works as expected. What error? Sure you got the curly brackets, parenthesizes, and braces correct?

Comment: Thanks Chris, gave you a great comment for your persintence/checking.  1) when /somepage is typed: goes into a loop /enenenenenenenenenenenenenenensomepage and gives error 2) when / is typed (just domain no page) it gives redirect error in firefox, nothing loads)

Comment: Repacing !^/../ with ![^/.]+ gives no errors, but also doesnt redirect /somepage to /en/somepage ... i have the feeling its the condition that is causing the error...  language folders are two lowercase chars. is !^([a-z][a-z])  a better condition? unfortunately loops also when /somepage is typet, giving a url like: /enenenenenenenenenenenenenenenenenenenenhome.php

Comment: It's possible your Apache server is interpreting something slightly different; try replacing `/en$1` in the rule with `/en/$1`. Are there any other rules in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Already did that, same: nothing appears. Firefox says redirection error. [hands in my hair from this problem!]

Comment: What version of Apache are you running? If you manually type in /en/somepage.php does it show up correctly?

Comment: @Sam, the first and last rule are going to start a mini-war. The first rule takes anything in the form /xx/asdf and makes it /asdf?ln=xx, the last will take that and make it /xx/asdf?ln=xx, which will trigger the first one again, causing a loop.

Comment: Gosh, i'm in all ways against any wars! so how should i make them sing peace? Perhaps the `Conditional rules` together with the `[ ]` endings can help to chain these three rules into one elegant rule. should i start a new question and mark yours as answered?

Comment: @Sam, it's probably be easiest to just edit the other rules into this question and include exactly how you want requests to be handled.

Comment: Dear Chris, thanks very much for your dedication! I am new to the community and already love it. Rephrased my entire question hope its much more clear. Curious to your new insights.

Comment: @Sam, yep, got it now I think.

Comment: Wauw looks prmising, before i check, i will just give you the well deserved points for a real answer, thanks so much! A note Chris, the language is always a two letter word (see in my question [a-z][a-z] which i believe covers that specific thing. While any actual page is a word, longer than two characters... Cant this information help separate the two sothat site.com/en/  or site.com/en both work without apache thinking /en is a page?

Comment: Thanks Chris. With the new rules in place on my Apache/2.0.54 (Fedora) each and every of the rules crash :( no results come out. Strange! old rules work good, except the last wish. Boy i wished i spoke this exotic Apache more fluently sothat i could get this fixed... sigh

Comment: @Sam, are there any error messages produced? It's all just perl regex and typical flow control (both of which take some getting used to).

Comment: have tried to catch the errors but firefox timeouts.. I just had a marvelous idea! i could install your code, remember the time, and then when the errors come, check immediately in the log files in my plesk account! perhaps i can see the error message there, cause the browser wont give any specific error... will check back soon. Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use. It will accept any languages and country.

```
# Tout pays de 2 digits et langue de 2 ou 3 digits ou juste la langue pas de pays - fonctionne bien et passe language et country
#www.country.com/index.html  devient www.country.com/index.php
#www.country.com/fr/index.html  devient www.country.com/index.php?language=fr
#www.country.com/ca/fr/index.html  devient www.country.com/index.php?country=ca&language=fr
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/([a-zA-Z]{2,3})/index\.html$ index.html?country=$1&language=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2,3})/index\.html$ index.html?language=$1
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.php [L]
```